# Proportion .each() .children() within a div

Tags: jquery

As 'parentDiv' gets smaller, I want 'childs' in 'parentDiv' to shrink proportionally.

This is working when there is only one 'child'.
But when I have more than one 'child', I want it to work so that each one's place and ratio are preserved.

How can I do that?

```
var parentDivLeft = $("#parentDiv").offset().left - $("#exDiv").offset().left;
var parentDivTop =  $("#parentDiv").offset().top - $("#exDiv").offset().top;

$('#parentDiv').width( ($('#parentDiv').width())*0.5 ).height( ($('#parentDiv').height())*0.5 );

var childWidth = $('#parentDiv').children().width();
var childHeight = $('#parentDiv').children().height();
var newChildWidth = childWidth * 0.5;
var newChildHeight = childHeight * 0.5;

$('#parentDiv').children().width( newChildWidth).height(newChildHeight); 

$('#parentDiv').children().each(function () {
    var childLeft = $("#parentDiv").children().offset().left - $("#parentDiv").offset().left  ;
    var childTop =  $("#parentDiv").children().offset().top - $("#parentDiv").offset().top ;
    var newChildLeft = childLeft * 0.5 ;
    var newChildTop =  childTop * 0.5 ;
    $("#parentDiv").children().css({top: newChildTop, left: newChildLeft});
});
```

There is an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/SemaK/5c4tpuzy/1/

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use percentage widths in CSS?

Comment: Yes, I need to know and store the position and width values..
I can not access these rates later.

Comment: Do note that `children().width()` will return the width of the first child only. If you want to do something for each child, use `children().each()`, as you are, but reference each child using `$(this)` instead of repeating `$("#parentDiv").children()`. Good idea to read [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

Comment: Should it be similar to this?

Comment: `$('#parentDiv').children().each(function () {
        var childLeft = $(this).each().offset().left - $("#parentDiv").offset().left;
        var childTop =  $(this).each().offset().top - $("#parentDiv").offset().top ;
        var newChildLeft = childLeft * 0.5 ;
        var newChildTop =  childTop * 0.5 ;
        $(this).each().css({top: newChildTop, left: newChildLeft});
    });  `

Comment: I solved the problem with your method. Thanks  @MikeMcCaughan